# Search for %character% in certain position

Tags: sql-server-2008

Currently creating a query where I need to find if position 5 in a column is a character or number. the field itself is obviously char but need to figure out how to differentiate

this is how I am finding the position:

```
substring(a.bin_num,5,1)
```

Comment: You are on the right track, any issues so far??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a safe way to proceed here would be to just compare the fifth character against the regex character range `[0-9]`, using the `LIKE` operator.  It was suggested in the comments above to use `ISNUMERIC()`, but there are caveats there.

```
SELECT
    bin_num,
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(bin_num, 5, 1) LIKE '[0-9]'
         THEN 'numeric'
         ELSE 'not numeric' END AS label
FROM yourTable
```

## Demo